# Can we invoke Angular JS typeahead kind even before you type

Tags: angularjs, mouse, typeahead

I am using angular js typeahead feature for a list of accounts in my application something like this.

```
typeahead="account for account in accounts | filter:$viewValue" .
```

I have all the accounts stored. The above feature works good. But I am trying to change this in such a way that when I just click the mouse on this input, it should display all the accounts. Can we achieve this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `minLength to 0` you should get all the results:

see: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/390